# Post JSON object to Watson Discovery from Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch, watson-discovery

I'm trying to take my google calendar and post each day as a document to watson discovery through google scripts. My code looks like this.

```
    var headers={
            "User-Agent": "CreateCalendarListJson",
            "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode( authdata.username+":"+authdata.password)
        };
        //headers.contentType="application/json";
        var parms={"headers":headers};
        url=newurl+"/v1/environments/"+discoveryData.environmentID+
          "/collections/"+discoveryData.collection_ID+"/documents/?version=2017-09-01";
        parms.method="POST";
        parms.file={
          'value':JSON.stringify(jsonEvent),
          'options':{
            'filename':jsonEvent.filename,
            'contentType':"application/json"
          }
        }
        console.info('discovery add document %s',JSON.stringify(parms));
        response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,parms);
```

However this gets an error 415 unsupported media type. Though application/json is a supported type and I've set contentType accordingly. Any suggestions?

The parms variable looks like this when UrlFetchApp.Fetch is run:

```
{"headers":
     {"User-Agent":"CreateCalendarListJson",
      "Authorization":"Basic ZTIyNTEwM............................tHcg=="},
      "method":"POST",
      "file":{"value":"{\"title\":\"Events 10/13/2017\",\"filename\":\"Events_10_13_2017\",\"text\":[{\"date\":\"10/13/2017\",\"summary\":\"assignment 1\"}]}",
      "options":{"filename":"Events_10_13_2017",
       "contentType":"application/json"}}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that documents to Watson Discovery must be passed as a multipart/form-data type. The following function will write a json text (store in jsonEvent.text) as a discovery document. Put the api endpoint in the 'newurl' and store discovery username and password in 'authdata' (json object), give the filename for the discovery document in 'filename'

```
function sendtodiscovery(url, jsonEvent, filename,authdata){
   var headers={
        "User-Agent": "CreateCalendarListJson",
        "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode( authdata.username+":"+authdata.password)
    };
    var parms={"headers":headers};
    var boundary="xxxxxxxx";  
    parms.method="POST";
    var data="--"+boundary+"\r\n"
    data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\""+filename+"\"\r\n";
    data += "Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n";
    console.info("data=%s",data);
    console.info("event=%s",JSON.stringify(jsonEvent));
    var payload=Utilities.newBlob(data).getBytes()
    .concat(Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(jsonEvent)).getBytes())
    .concat(Utilities.newBlob("\r\n--"+boundary+"--\r\n\r\n").getBytes());

    parms.contentType="multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary;
    parms.payload=payload;
    //parms.muteHttpExceptions=true;
    console.info('discovery add document %s',JSON.stringify(parms));
    return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,parms);
 }
```